# How to avoid generating a very small computational error in perl

Tags: perl, numeric

```
my $a = 243300;
my $b = 3000;
my $c = 81.10;

if (($a - $b * $c) != 0) {
    warn "delta is " . ($a - $b * $c);
} else {
    print "OK\n";
}
```

The result produces a very small difference as:

```
Mac: ~ # perl f.pl
delta is 2.91038304567337e-11 at f.pl line 6.
```

I can work-around by comparing with 0.01 but how to avoid such problem and how come the very small difference?

Comment: This is about [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) in general.  There's very little of Perl specifics, mostly irrelevant for writing correct and solid code -- no more than there's in any language.  (In short -- yes, you generally need to use a (_relative_) error.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an arbitrary-precision numerical package like [`Math::BigRat`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigRat),[`Math::BigFloat`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigFloat), or [`Math::Decimal`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Decimal), but this will come with a significant performance penalty.

```
use Math::Decimal qw(dec_sub dec_mul);
my ($a,$b,$c,$delta);
$a = 243300;
$b = 3000;
$c = 81.10;
$delta = dec_sub($a, dec_mul($b,$c));
if ($delta != 0) {
    warn "delta [M::D]is $delta\n";
} else {
    print "OK [M::D]\n";
}
```

---

```
use Math::BigRat;
$a = Math::BigRat->new(243300);
$b = Math::BigRat->new(3000);
$c = Math::BigRat->new(81.10);
$delta = $a - $b * $c;
if ($delta != 0) {
    warn "delta [M::BR]is $delta\n";
} else {
    print "OK [M::BR]\n";
}
```